# Returning -infty in R

Tags: r

In my code I'm first doing a column wise product of a matrix, which gives me a vector and then these elements are added up and then finally I take the log of this scalar. Some of the elements are really close to zero, i.e. something like 10^(-250) and when multiplied together I get an even smaller number say 10^(-400).

Here is a little example:

```
             1. column       2. column         product
1. row       10^(-250)       10^(-150)        10^(-400)
2. row       10^(-250)     10^(-150)          10^(-400)
```

so

```
log(10^(-400)+10^(-400))=-infty.
```

When I actually should get something like this:

```
log(2*10^(-400))=log(2)-400*log(10)=-400
```

Here is my code as well:

```
R=500
theta_draw=rnorm(R,0,1)
theta_draw=t(replicate((T-1),theta_draw))

    reprobit<-function(i,v,v_select,gamma,sigma_eta){
         ll_r_t=pnorm(((2*v[((i-1)*(T-1)+1):((i-1)*(T-1)+(T-1))]-
           rep(1,(T-1)))%*%t(rep(1,R)))*
               (v_select[((i-1)*(T-1)+1):((i-1)*(T-1)+(T-1)),] %*%
               gamma%*%rep(1,R)+sigma_eta*theta_draw))
        return(ll_r_t)
    }

    likelihood<-function(gamma,sigma_eta){
         for (i in 1:N){
           ll_i[i]=log(mean(apply(reprobit(i,v,v_select,gamma,sigma_eta), 
                    1, prod)))
         }
         ll=sum(ll_i)
    return(ll)
 }
```

Is there a way to get around this?

Thanks

Comment: numerically 10^(-400) is 0 and log(0) is -inf ... R is not your platform for symbolical math calculations

Comment: If it is a real data problem then there is seldom any way around log(near-0) than adding a very slight +ve number to low values....

Comment: .. or rewrite the rest of code to use the log values themselves??

Comment: I think this is what you need: http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2012/07/26/avoiding-underflow-in-bayesian-computations/

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to read to the blog.